# How to force CI to use the latest pods after project was moved to Xcode 10 and latest wift 4.2?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, fastlane, xcode10

The question is because we see an error after moving project to the latest Xcode 10 and Swift 4.2:

My fastfile looks like:

```
before_all do
  xcversion(version: "10.0")
end
```

```
lane :test do
  scan(scheme: SCHEME_NAME, code_coverage: true, output_directory: OUTPUT_PATH + 'tests')
  xcov(
    scheme: SCHEME_NAME, 
    workspace: WORKSPACE_FILE_PATH, 
    json_report: true, 
    markdown_report: true, 
    output_directory: OUTPUT_PATH + "coverage", 
    skip_slack: true,
    only_project_targets: true
  )
end
```

and **gitlab-ci.yml**:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy
  - export

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - bundle exec pod repo update
    - bundle exec pod install
    - export
  after_script:
    - rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives || true
  artifacts:
    name: "Staff_${CI_PIPELINE_ID}"
    paths:
      - Pods/*
      - Staff.xcworkspace
  when: on_success
  tags:
      - iOS

test:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - killall "Simulator" || true
  script:
    - bundle exec fastlane snapshot reset_simulators --force
    - bundle exec fastlane test
  after_script:
    - killall "Simulator" || true
    - rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives || true
  artifacts:
    name: "Staff_${CI_PIPELINE_ID}"
    paths:
      - fastlane/output/coverage
  when: on_success
  tags:
    - iOS
```

[image]

Comment: You need to ensure that each pod is installing a version that supports Swift 4.2. Check your pod install phase on your CI too and make sure that it runs `pod repo update` before installing/updating pods as it may not know of any updated versions. There is also a setting in the project settings for SWIFT_VERSION. Check it is set to Swift 4.2

Comment: as you can see `pod repo update` is called BEFORE `pod install` under `build` stage.

Comment: I couldnt see that properly as it wasnt formatted very well. can you build locally on your own machine without any issues?

Comment: yes, I can build locally without any issues. But LOCALLY every pod has Swift version set to 4 instead of 4.2. Why it needs 4.2 on CI?

Comment: Does your CI server even have Swift 4.2 installed?, scrap that question. it must have to get the errors you are getting

Comment: compare pod version installed on your local to those on CI server

Comment: `cocoapods 1.5.3` on both: CI and local. Server has xcode 10 installed... so how to force pods to use older swift version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180352/discussion-between-bartlomiej-semanczyk-and-scriptable).

Comment: I meant the individual pods that are being installed. As it appears that at the least CMMarkdownKit Pod is not a version that is updated for Swift 4.2 as the errors suggest the CI is using the Swift 4.2 compiler but the Pod isn't ready for Swift 4.2. check which version of this pod you have local and on server

Comment: Sorry I'm on a secure network and cant access chat

Comment: @Scriptable I added another related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52408345/fastlane-tests-ended-with-success-but-failed-finally. Could you look at that?