# Fastlane tests ended with success but failed finally

Tags: xcode, fastlane

Why doesn't it finish lane properly?

[image]

[image]

Console output with `--verbose` option:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/interface.rb:172:in `test_failure!': [!] Test execution failed. Exit status: 1 (FastlaneCore::Interface::FastlaneTestFailure)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/ui.rb:17:in `method_missing'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/scan/lib/scan/runner.rb:87:in `handle_results'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/scan/lib/scan/runner.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/scan/lib/scan/manager.rb:18:in `work'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/run_tests.rb:23:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in execute_action'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/actions_helper.rb:50:in `execute_action'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:232:in `block in execute_action'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:227:in `chdir'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:227:in `execute_action'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:157:in `trigger_action_by_name'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:149:in `method_missing'
    from Fastfile:109:in `block in parsing_binding'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:49:in `block in execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `chdir'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `execute'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:56:in `cruise_lane'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:36:in `handle'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in `call'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:153:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:476:in `run_active_command'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:74:in `run!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/delegates.rb:15:in `run!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:333:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:41:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:108:in `take_off'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.104.0/bin/fastlane:20:in `'
    from /usr/local/bin/fastlane:22:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/fastlane:22:in `'
```

[image]

Comment: How are you running those tests? The process returned "exit status" 1, which it should not do but return 0 if everything went well.

Comment: How do I run tests? fastlane test.

Comment: And what exactly does that `test` lane do?

Comment: read that related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52406240/2725435

Comment: @janpio I updated the question with console output with `--verbose` option.

Comment: The screenshot with exit status 65 doesn't match the rest of what you posted. How are those connected? The `--verbose` output is nice, but the rest _before_ the stacktrace is the relevant bit - why does `scan` return status code 1 when it says it was successful?